# Displaying selected image on screen using UIIamgePickerControllerDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uiimage

I am attempting to learn more about the delegate pattern. I have written an app that accesses the user's camera roll and I want to display that image on the view controller after the user selects the image. Here is what I have thus far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePickerView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    // Delegate Methods
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imagePickerView.image = image
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func pickAnImage(_ sender: Any) {

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The camera roll appears as expected and the Cancel buttons dismiss the modal. Selecting an image also dismisses the modal, however that image is not displayed on the screen. I have confirmed that my `imagePickerController` is corrected referenced as an outlet. What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing pickerController.delegate = self before the present

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to dismiss the controller once the image is selected, maybe the following detailed function will help you.

For Swift 4.2:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        imageView.image = selectedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Before Swift 4.2:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        imageView.image = selectedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Since I've received many points from this answer I'm adding a more concise answer (Just one line is required for setting the image to imageView).

Bonus Answer:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    imageView.image = (info[.editedImage] ?? info[.originalImage]) as? UIImage
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Yea, the dismissal of the controller was a step I was missing. That, and the assignment of the delegate. Beginner mistakes.

Comment: Good, keep coding and do more research before asking here, or else someone could just mark your question as duplicate.

Comment: wwooowww, i try any code failed, but your code very very membantu

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the view controller as the delegate of pickerController

// pickerController.delegate  = self

Also check the imagePickerView outlet is connected.

Comment: Man, that's about as beginner of a mistake as I could make. I do have one additional question. When I select the image, the modal isn't dismissed. The image will display on screen after I select an image and the press Cancel. How do I skip that last step?

Comment: Also, is creating the reference to the delegate and assigning the delegate inside of the pickAnImage method a good idea? I've seen these declared at the beginning of the class and inside of methods. I'm unsure which is best practice.

Comment: Dismiss the picker when selected also. Delegate reference is kept by UIImagePickerController. We do not have to worry. But the idea is these assignment is not needed to be when the button is clicked, since assigning delegate can be done at the loading time. In button click only present the picker. (In this way you have to keep global reference for picker)

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure you have made all inclusions in the info.plist file
- Ensure you have all the delegates set
- Ensure what you are using to display image (e.g if editing is set to true, then `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` else `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`)